# Texture not mapping to some polys

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: material preview and uv map]

As you can see from my material preview and uv map image, the polygons that are currently selected are part of the same object and uv map yet have no texture.

I have made a character from quads as one object, applied seams and attempted to map a texture to the character. First attempt had the whole character stuck as white, no material assignments would have an affect and now only some polys are textured

Comment: hello, do you mean that this part should be textured with the same grid but is not? Maybe because you haven't assigned the same material to these parts? If it's not your problem, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: there is only the one solid object in my scene, yes it all should be covered by the color grid.

I didnt end up saving that exact file but the closest one can replicate the results without me marking all the seems so I have uploaded it [link](https://pasteall.org/blend/c8cf42a4c41148d89198d6913e7de65d)

Comment: the white part doesn't have any material, see in the material panel

Comment: now im just more confused, about how only part of my object got assigned a material in the first place

Comment: you need to learn how to manage materials, maybe watch a tutorial on this matter